# Serviceclass implementing the jparepository always returns null in spring boot app

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new to java and spring boot. 
I have created a simple spring app which fetches student details from the database using the JPArepository.
Following is the studentDetais entity:

```js
package com.example.webcustomertracker.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "StudentDetails")
public class StudentDetails {
 
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
 private Integer StudentID;
 private String Name;
 private String Surname;
 private String City;
 
 public StudentDetails() {}

 public String getName() {
  return Name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  Name = name;
 }

 public String getSurname() {
  return Surname;
 }

 public void setSurname(String surname) {
  Surname = surname;
 }

 public String getCity() {
  return City;
 }

 public void setCity(String city) {
  City = city;
 }

 public StudentDetails(String name, String surname, String city) {
  Name = name;
  Surname = surname;
  City = city;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "StudentDetails [Name=" + Name + ", Surname=" + Surname + ", City=" + City + "]";
 }
 
 

}
```

Following is the JPARepo:

```js
  package com.example.webcustomertracker.data; 
  
  import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

  import com.example.webcustomertracker.entity.StudentDetails;
  
  public interface StudentDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentDetails, Integer> 
  { 
    
  }
```

Following is the service class:

```js
package com.example.webcustomertracker.data;

import java.util.Optional;

import com.example.webcustomertracker.entity.StudentDetails;

public interface StudentDetailsService {

 public abstract Optional<StudentDetails> getStudentDetails(int StudentId);
}
```

Following is the service class implementation

```js
package com.example.webcustomertracker.data;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.webcustomertracker.entity.StudentDetails;

@Component
public class StudentDetailsDataAccess implements StudentDetailsService {

 private StudentDetailsRepository studentDetailsRepository;
 
 public StudentDetailsDataAccess(StudentDetailsRepository theStudentDetailsRepository) {
  this.studentDetailsRepository = theStudentDetailsRepository;    
 }

 @Transactional
 public Optional<StudentDetails> getStudentDetails(int StudentId) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  Optional<StudentDetails> objStud =  this.studentDetailsRepository.findById(StudentId);
  
  
  
  return objStud;
 }
 
 
 
}
```

Following is the main class which boots the spring framework. I am just trying to call one of the functions of service but the service instance is coming as null and it is failing to execute.

```js
package com.example.webcustomertracker;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.example.webcustomertracker.data.StudentDetailsDataAccess;
import com.example.webcustomertracker.data.StudentDetailsService;
import com.example.webcustomertracker.entity.StudentDetails;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebCustomerTrackerApplication {
    
    @Autowired
  private StudentDetailsService studentDetailsService;

 public Optional<StudentDetails> getTheStudentDetails(int id) {
  return studentDetailsService.getStudentDetails(id);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(WebCustomerTrackerApplication.class, args); 
  
  Optional<StudentDetails> objStudent = new WebCustomerTrackerApplication().getTheStudentDetails(11);

 }

 
}
```

Following is the error I am getting after running the code:

```js
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.example.webcustomertracker.WebCustomerTrackerApplication.getTheStudentDetails(WebCustomerTrackerApplication.java:20)
 at com.example.webcustomertracker.WebCustomerTrackerApplication.main(WebCustomerTrackerApplication.java:26)
```

Comment: you need to autowire StudentDetailsService

Comment: Did........... still same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Autowire in Controller layer.

Say you have any controller called IndexController
auto wire there.

for example

```
    StudentDetailsService studentService;
    @Autowired
    public IndexController(StudentDetailsService studentService){
Optional<StudentDetails> objStudent = new studentService.getTheStudentDetails(11);
}
```

Comment: So you mean to say, I can not use service in main method. JPA Data will only be used with controller ?

Comment: you can use but, you will get Nullpointerexception. because you are using service immediately after Application.run() by that time service object is not created.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be,

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class WebCustomerTrackerApplication {

    @Autowired
    private StudentDetailsService studentDetailsService;

    public Optional<StudentDetails> getTheStudentDetails(int id) {
        return studentDetailsService.getStudentDetails(id);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(WebCustomerTrackerApplication.class, args); 
        Thread.sleep(1500);
        Optional<StudentDetails> objStudent = new WebCustomerTrackerApplication().getTheStudentDetails(11);

    }

}
```

here it is waiting until the application is started(all components are loaded).
by this time you won't get null pointer exception since service object created.

Comment: it is dependency injection(constructor level). since constructor in the controller is requires service object. so it is instantiating the service by the time of creating of controller

Comment: How do i call the controller once developed ? 
Main method gets called once the application is booted. 
How to call controller  ?

Comment: are you using controllers in your application or not?